# Why is impredicative polymorphism allowed only for functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, rank-n-types, impredicativetypes

In Haskell I can't write

```
f :: [forall a. a -> a]
f = [id]
```

because

```
• Illegal polymorphic type: forall a. a -> a
  GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism
```

But I can happily do

```
f :: (forall a. a -> a) -> (a, b) -> (a, b)
f i (x, y) = (i x, i y)
```

So as I see GHC does support impredicative polymorphism which is contradict to the error message above. Why is the `(->)` type constructor treated specially in this case? What prevents GHC from having this feature generalized over all datatypes?

Comment: It may have to do with the recursive nature of `[]`. The function only requires `RankNTypes` to be enabled. (Strictly speaking, `Rank2Types` would suffice, were it not superseded by `RankNTypes`.) It's `[]` which is special, not `(->)`.

Comment: @chepner it is `(->)` that's special: `Maybe (forall a . a)` is a subtype of `forall a . Maybe a` in that every value of the first type is admissible when the second is expected but not vice-versa; ie impredicative polymorphism is disallowed for `Maybe` and `[]` for exactly the same reason.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Higher-rank polymorphism is a special case of impredicative polymorphism, where the type constructor is `(->)` instead of any arbitrary constructor like `[]`.

The basic problems with impredicativity are that it makes type *checking* hard and type *inference* impossible in the general case—and indeed we can’t infer types of a higher rank than 2: you have to provide a type annotation. This is the ostensible reason for the existence of the `Rank2Types` extension separate from `RankNTypes`, although in GHC they’re synonymous.

However, for the restricted case of `(->)`, there are simplified algorithms for checking these types and doing the necessary amount of inference along the way for the programmer’s convenience, such as [Complete and Easy Bidirectional Type Checking for Higher-rank Polymorphism](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Enk480/bidir.pdf)—compare that to the complexity of [Boxy Types: Inference for Higher-rank Types and Impredicativity](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1291&context=cis_papers).

The actual reasons in GHC are partly historical: there had been an `ImpredicativeTypes` extension, which was deprecated because it never worked properly or ergonomically. Part of the problem was that we didn’t yet have the `TypeApplications` extension, so there was no convenient way to explicitly supply a polymorphic type as a type argument, and the compiler attempted to do more inference than it ought to. In GHC 9.2, [`ImpredicativeTypes`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/impredicative_types.html) has come out of retirement, thanks to [GHC proposal 274](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0274-quick-look-impredicativity.rst) and an algorithm, [Quick Look](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/a-quick-look-at-impredicativity/), that infers a predictable subset of impredicative types.

In the absence of `ImpredicativeTypes`, there have been alternatives for a while: with `RankNTypes`, you can “hide” other forms of impredicativity by wrapping the polymorphic type in a `newtype` and explicitly packing & unpacking it to tell the compiler exactly where you want to generalise and instantiate type variables.

```
newtype Id = Id { unId :: forall a. a -> a }

f :: [Id]
f = [Id id]  -- generalise

(unId (head f) (), unId (head f) 'x')  -- instantiate to () and Char
```